# Upload doesnt work in my webview app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

On some pages of my website there are options to upload files and content. I have created a webview application out of the website using android studio. In my application, when I click upload contents, nothing happens. It doesn't open any directory to upload.

But, if I use the website from a mobile browser it works fine and when I press 'attach', it opens up the phones's directory/storage which is not the case for my webview app. What is the problem with my android application?

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: is it show the white blank page when are you click on button?

Comment: Check my Answer. hope it works for you, i also using this.

Answer (score 0):

Please enable javascript using `webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`